# Grails Jquery validation stop working when use library

Tags: jquery, grails

I just downloaded the jquery plugin into my grails application. The validation stop working. I noted that if I remove what I put in head the validation works.

I put in the gsp head

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

Config.groovy

```
grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"
```

call validation in gsp body

```
<g:javascript src="submit.js"/>
```

submit.js

```
$(function () {  


    $("#addDiseaseForm").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        rules: { 

            commonName: { 
                required: true      
            },
            scientificName: { 
                required: true      
            },

            imagedisease: {
                required: true,
                accept: "jpg|png|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF|gif|bmp|BMP"
            },
            imagesymptom: {
                required: true,
                accept: "jpg|png|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF|gif|bmp|BMP"
            },
            description: { 
                required: true      
            },
            virus: { 
                required: true      
            },
            spread: { 
                required: true      
            },
            prevent: {
                required: true
            },
            product:{
                required : true
            },
            supplier:{
                required : true                
            }, 
            projectddl: {
                required: true
            }







        } 
    }); 

});
```

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove from head does not affect remote function.

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had many troubles in jQuery and validation in my first project, now my solution is to create a module in ApplicationRessources.groovy (or two for jQuery UI), and set the path to the jQuery library in the js folder.

ApplicationRessources.groovy

```
jquery_min{
        resource url:"js/jquery.js"
...
```

and use r:require in your view